# How to execute two queries at the same time in VB? (MySql)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What's the most efficient way to execute two queries at the same time?
I want to execute two INSERT sql queries (different tables) simultaneously when I click the submit button. is it possible?

**Here's what I did:**

```
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; user id = root;password = ; database = ddap_hr")
    Dim sqlQuery1 As String = "INSERT INTO applicants VALUES ( '" & lblID.Text & "' , '" & txtLName.Text & "','" & txtFName.Text & "','" & txtMName.Text & "','" & cmboGender.Text & "','" & mtxtAge.Text & "','" & dtpBdate.Value & "','" & cmboStatus.Text & "','" & txtSSS.Text & "','" & txtTin.Text & "','" & txtReligion.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & mtxtContactNum.Text & "','" & txtEmail.Text & "')"
    Dim sqlQuery2 As String = "INSERT INTO appli_idgen(Lzero) VALUES ('" & lblNum.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery1)
    Dim cmd2 As New MySqlCommand(sqlQuery2)
    Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader

    Dim ConfirmMsg = MessageBox.Show("Are all the datas correct?" & Environment.NewLine & "   • Last Name:  " & txtLName.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • First Name:  " & txtFName.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Middle Name:  " & txtMName.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Gender:  " & cmboGender.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Age:  " & mtxtAge.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Date of Birth:  " & dtpBdate.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Status:  " & cmboStatus.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • SSS:  " & txtSSS.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • TIN:  " & txtTin.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Religion:  " & txtReligion.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Address:  " & txtAddress.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • Contact Number:  " & mtxtContactNum.Text & Environment.NewLine & "   • E-mail:  " & txtEmail.Text & Environment.NewLine, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, False)

    If ConfirmMsg = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Try
            Try
                cmd1.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                rdr.Read()
            Catch ex1 As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex1.Message.ToString)
            Finally
                conn.Close()
            End Try

            Try
                cmd2.Connection = conn
                conn.Open()
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
                rdr.Read()
            Catch ex2 As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex2.Message.ToString)
            Finally
                conn.Close()
            End Try
        Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally
            Dim addAnother = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to add another applicant?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, False)
            If addAnother = MsgBoxResult.No Then
               Me.Close()
               Main_home.Refresh()
            End If
        End Try

    End If
```

I want to reduce the line of codes as much sa possible. I need your help. btw I'm using MySql. Sorry cause I'm new in VB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please rephrase and this time be more precise.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I want to execute two different queries at the same time.

Comment: Do you have a code that gets triggered when you click the submit button?

Comment: I do. Sorry if I didn't include it at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you've shown us what you've tried, friend.

As it stands, you can create a subroutine which will execute Nonquery to MySQL then CALL that sub TWICE on any trigger(button, checkbox, etc.):

Note: this requires you know how to use the MySQL connector for .NET You can look for more on that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net.html)

```
   Public Sub MyNonQuery(ByVal SQCommand as String)
      Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=your server ip; port=the server port; uid='your user id';password ='your password';")

      Dim SQLCMD as new MySqlCommand(SQCommand, conn)

      conn.open()
      SQLCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
      conn.close()
    End Sub
```

Now you can use this sub in the following manner(s):

1. CALL it twice

   ```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

       MyNonQuery("Insert into db.tbl1 values(...);")
       MyNonQuery("Insert into db.tbl2 values(...);")

    End Sub
   ```
2. On a single call, Send TWO SQL commands

   ```
     Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

       MyNonQuery("Insert into db.tbl1 values(...); Insert into db.tbl2 values(...);")


    End Sub
   ```

Remember to properly Clean the data from the user though, to prevent SQL Injection attacks. Ultimately I would suggest you look into studying [Stored Procedures](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,358569)

Comment: Sir, I got this lil' prob. The query is executed twice. And I got this Duplicate Primary error because of that. Pls help. Thank you. My code: [link](http://puu.sh/5vyRN.txt)

Comment: Do your tables have primary keys? Because that error means that you are trying to insert a column with a primary key that already exists in that particular table.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question you could try and start two threads running one immeddiately after the other. This is effectively having them run at the same time.

```
Private Sub Button36_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button36.Click
    Dim t1 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Insert1)
    Dim t2 As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Insert2)
    t1.Start()
    t2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Insert1()
    'do insert here
End Sub

Private Sub Insert2()
    'do insert here
End Sub
```

Whether you will get any performance improvement I doubt.

Answer (score 0):

im late but try this, hope it helps

```
Public Sub CreateCommand(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_example ..."
        Dim query2 As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_add ..." 
        Dim QueryString As String = String.Concat(query,";",query2)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(QueryString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using 
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this web or windows based?

Windows forms - do as above comment

```
'Web forms
Private Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
    'do insert 1 here
    'do insert 2 here
End Sub
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the question, friend. Perhaps you would like to edit it to include new helpful details?